# Handling Store.save() for records that contains DS.BelongsTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a blog that uses JSON to communicate between Rails with Active Model Serializers v0.10.0.rc2 and Ember.js. Everything was working until I needed to implement DS.BelongsTo on the **Post** model for getting the tag name from the **Genre** model.

Most of it (especially server side) seems to be working as {{model.genre.name}) does display the genre name for posts created on the server side (seeds.rb), but things always turns sour when I try to create a post on the Ember side... I tried different ways, but I just can't get the genre_id to be saved with the post (user_id is saved though and it is probably because I did not setup a BelongsTo relationship to it.)

**Post Create.js Controller**

```
application: Ember.inject.controller('application'),
genreID: Ember.computed('application.selectedGID', function()
{
    return this.get('application.selectedGID');
}),

var store = this.store;
console.log(this.get('genreID')); //>> 1
var post = store.createRecord('post', {
    user_id: this.get('session.secure.userId'),
    genre_id: this.get('genreID'), //>> Was working before BelongsTo
    ...
    genre: store.find('genre', this.get('genreID')) //>> Supposed to work, but does not...
});
console.log(post.get('genre_id')); //>> 1
console.log(post.genre); //>> Computed Property
console.log(post.genre.id); //>> Undefined
console.log(post.get('genre.id'));  //>> Undefined
console.log(post.genre.name); //>> Undefined
console.log(post.get('genre.name'));  //>> Undefined
post.save().then(function() {
    self.transitionToRoute('post', post);
}, function() {
    alert('Failed to create Post...');
});
```

**Post Index.js controller**

```
posts/1 << Created with seeds.rb

console.log(this.get('model.genre.id')); //>> 1
console.log(this.get('model.genre.name')); //>> Song

posts/18 << Created on Ember.js

console.log(this.get('model.genre.id')); //>> undefined
console.log(this.get('model.genre.name')); //>> undefined
```

**Terminal**

```
Processing by Api::V1::PostsController#create as JSON

Parameters: {"post"=>{"user_id"=>4, "fact_link"=>"bcvxvbxcbvxc", "fiction_link"=>"vbxcbcvxvbxcvbxc", "title"=>"vbxcxbvbxvccxvb", "importance"=>nil, "soft_delete"=>false, "soft_delete_date"=>nil, "hidden"=>false, "views_count"=>nil, "text"=>"bvxcbvcxbvcxvbxc", "comments_count"=>nil, "genre_id"=>nil, "fact_type_id"=>nil, "category_id"=>nil, "topic_id"=>nil}}

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "user@example.com"]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction

SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("text", "views_count", "title", "user_id", "fact_link", "fiction_link", "soft_delete", "hidden", "comments_count", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["text", "bvxcbvcxbvcxvbxc"], ["views_count", nil], ["title", "vbxcxbvbxvccxvb"], ["user_id", 4], ["fact_link", "bcvxvbxcbvxc"], ["fiction_link", "vbxcbcvxvbxcvbxc"], ["soft_delete", "f"], ["hidden", "f"], ["comments_count", nil], ["created_at", "2015-08-21 17:27:01.399594"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-21 17:27:01.399594"]]

User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]

SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "posts_count" = COALESCE("posts_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]

(17.5ms)  commit transaction
```

**Genre Model**

```
posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true})
name: DS.attr ('string'),
```

**Post Model**

```
user_id: DS.attr ('number'), 
genre_id: DS.attr ('number'),
...
genre: DS.belongsTo('genre', {async: true})
```

The entire source code can be found on my [Github](https://github.com/Deovandski/fakktion), but I could add more code snippets here if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure if using Ruby on Rails backend or expressjs with sequilize?

Comment: Ruby on Rails. You can check the Gemfile [here](https://github.com/Deovandski/Fakktion/blob/master/Gemfile)

Comment: `posts: DS.hasMany('posts', {async: true})` should be `posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true})`

Comment: I fixed it, but the error still remains... I will update the question with the new information and I will also add a few more code snippets. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what is stated in the Ember.js [guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/creating-and-deleting-records/), the solution somehow ended up being to use `peekRecord` instead of `find` or `findRecord` as described below:

```
genre: store.peekRecord('genre', this.get('genreID'))
```

I believe that the cause of this issue was the promise created by find and findRecord that did not got resolved before the store.save() was called.

Comment: On a sidenote, can anyone explain to me the downvote? It would be helpful to know why...